# Issue with Rectangle of Asterisks Java MOOC 39.3

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

So I'm sure this is a familiar problem as I've seen answers all over but I'm having a particular hard time with this part of it. I feel like I'm close but some of the outputs are just strange. Almost like it is being multiplied(?) somehow. Hopefully the outputs provide clarity about what I mean. With where I am in this MOOC course I'm pretty sure I'm intended to use while loops while calling the original printStars method so I want to keep my code as similar to that as possible.

```
public class HelloWorld {
private static void printStars(int amount) {
int i = 0;
while (i<amount) {
  System.out.print("*");
  i++;
 }
}
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height){
 int i = 0;
  while(i < height){
    int j = 0;
      while(j < width){
        printStars(width);
        j++;
}
System.out.println();
i++;
 }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
printRectangle(width,height);    
 }
}
```

Note that the width and height in the printRectangle method above are not actually my code but just substitute for the example outputs below:

printRectangle(1,2):

```
*
*
```

printRectangle(1,5):

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

It seems to work correctly with at least the height but once I start testing with the width it gets all screwed up

printRectangle(2,2):

```
****
****
```

printRectangle(3,2):

```
*********
*********
```

The height still seems to work fine though even though the width is all bizarre

printRectangle(2,3):

```
****
****
****
```

printRectangle(3,3):

```
*********
*********
*********
```

It's so strange and I honestly don't know why it's doing this. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm not seeing but I've been stuck on this for hours and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused: you show `printRectangle(2,3)` twice, with two different results. Is that correct, or a typo?

Comment: Apologies! The first (2,3) is actually (3,2). Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop to print the rectangle is enough. You don't need the extra print method. Or you don't need an extra loop choice is yours.

Something like this:

```
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height){
 int i = 0;
  while(i < height){
    int j = 0;
      while(j < width){
        System.out.print("*");
        j++;
}
System.out.println();
i++;
 }
}
```

Or

```
private static void printStars(int amount) {
int i = 0;
while (i<amount) {
  System.out.print("*");
  i++;
 }
}
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height){
 int i = 0;
  while(i < height){
         printStars(width);
}
System.out.println();
i++;
 }
}
```

Either one will work!!

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you're printing lines that are the width of your intended width *squared*.  This is because you have the call to `printStars` inside a `while` loop within the `printRectangle` method.  However, you have another `while` loop inside `printStars` itself.  Because of this you get width * width stars.

In `printRectangle`, there is no need for the inner `while` loop; just call `printStars`, still within the outer `while` loop on `height`, still before the printing of the newline.